# Unable to install docker 1.5 on ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

Currently I have docker 1.0 verion in my vm(Ubuntu 14.04 64bit) I want to upgrade it to latest version(1.5) but facing some issue. Kindly help.

First I tried getting key with below command, it is successful.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options https-proxy="http://p72293:peedeE(6)@172.18.1.38:8080/" --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
```

Second, I do `"sudo apt-get update"` but I get below error message for get.docker.com

> W: Failed to fetch
>   https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/dists/docker/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   W: Failed to fetch
>   https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/dists/docker/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Third, I do `sudo apt-get install lxc-docker` but I get below error.

> E: Unable to locate package lxc-docker

Kindly help me to resolve this issue and upgrade to newer version. I want to use --bridge option which is not available in 1.0.

Note: I am behind a proxy. But all required setting is done.

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc for Ubuntu installation at https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/ or you can try the script that guesses your OS and installs `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh`

Comment: Tried abov command but still getting below error message.curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.docker.com port 443: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using 64-bit ubuntu? I was using 32-bit ubuntu and that was the reason of error. Then I changed it to 64-bit, that was the fix.

```
Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your Ubuntu version.
```

Details is here https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/ and here http://blog.marcelotmelo.com/linux/ubuntu/vagrant-and-docker-provisioner/